# How to access a Spring Boot Application's name programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've defined an application name using the bootstrap.yml file in my spring boot application.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: abc
```

How can i get this application name during runtime/programmatically ?

Answer (score 65):

You should be able to use the @Value annotation to access any property you set in a properties/YAML file:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String appName;
```

Comment: This works for application.yml/application.properties, but doesn't work for bootstrap.yml. Is there anything that needs to be configured? some annotation, somewhere?

Comment: You can override `spring.config.name` to "bootstrap" (defaults to "application") or go further by specifying a different configuration explicitly using `spring.config.location`.

Comment: Value annotation is no longer recommended

Comment: this literally does not answer the question. OP clearly stated "bootstrap.yaml", which this fails to address.

Comment: ok, but why if you don't explicit set the property the value is null ??

Answer (score 27):

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;    
...
this.applicationContext.getId();
```

Please, find this:

```
# IDENTITY (ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer)
spring.application.name=
spring.application.index=
```

In Spring Boot [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

And follow with source code for that `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` class:

```
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    applicationContext.setId(getApplicationId(applicationContext.getEnvironment()));
}
```

Where the default behavior is with this:

```
/**
 * Placeholder pattern to resolve for application name
 */
private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "${vcap.application.name:${spring.application.name:${spring.config.name:application}}}";
```

Comment: The question asks for the application name, not the application ID.

Comment: The application ID is the application name. For me, the `getApplicationName()` returns nothing and `getApplicationId()` returns the name of the application, as set with the `spring.application.name` property.

Comment: `getId()` returns a combination of the value of `spring.application.name` and `spring.application.index`. if no index value is set, it is defaulted. in my case calling `getId()` returns `my-application-1` when the value of `spring.application.name` is `my-application`

Answer (score 7):

Since the `@Value` annotation is discouraged in Spring Boot when referencing configuration properties, and because `applicationContext.getId();` doesn't always return the value of `spring.application.name` another way is to get the value from the Environment directly

```
private final Environment environment;

...

public MyBean(final Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

...

private getApplicationName() {
    return this.environment.get("spring.application.name");
}
```

Another possible way would be to create your own ConfigurationProperties class to get access to the value.

I'm not saying these are the best ways, and I hope/wish that there is a better way, but it is a way.

Comment: do you have an authoritative source that the value annotation is discouraged? The Spring Boot documentation does not seem to support that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: I found this: "Using the @Value("${property}") annotation to inject configuration properties can sometimes be cumbersome, especially if you are working with multiple properties or your data is hierarchical in nature" and a discussion of differences between `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative source. I did read it in Springs own documentation at some point, but maybe that's since changed. The idea is that configuration, when using Spring Boot, is best to come from the use of configuration properties so that the application can validate the configuration and fail on startup if any validation failed.

Comment: The issue I've seen in the real world is that developers will use the `@Value` annotation to access a property by name directly. If that property is not set or not of the expected type, the application can fail while performing runtime operations. It also makes finding usage of such configuration harder.

Comment: I find it much safer to define all configuration in configuration classes an access the properties from them as injected beans. Accessing from the class directly isn't always obvious in some cases like where an annotation is required. In these cases, because it's SPEL, you can access the configuration property from the bean using the SPEL syntax `#{myConfigProps.myConfig}`.

Comment: The way @loesak is doing it is the way I see spring devs doing it in other libraries. It seems this result should be higher-ranked.

Answer (score 2):

Note! If your using a SpringBootTest, you need to suplly the properties/yml.
Otherwise, the environment/appcontext does not load the config files.
The, your app name is not set.
Like so:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
....
```

Answer (score 1):

This post is aged but I hate unanswered questions.
So use the following snippet:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name [: defaultValue]}") 
private String appName;
```

What is between [] is optional.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a really ugly way to do this, but it works so I'm not searching further. Maybe this will help someone.

The basic premise is that spring Environment stores the value inside a propertySource.. It appears that bootstrap config is stored in the ResourcePropertySource and so you can get it from that. For me it is currently throwing an exception, but then I can get the value out of the exception, so I haven't looked any further:

```java
    try {
        this.environment.getProperty("name", ResourcePropertySource.class);
    } catch (ConversionFailedException e) {
        String res = (String)e.getValue();
    }
```

And then you can just do this for every property you are interested in.

Like I said ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the advice to put the definition of [spring.application.name in bootstrap.properties/yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997352/what-is-the-difference-between-putting-a-property-on-application-yml-or-bootstra) . But what happens if it is defined in different ways and also multiple times.

Possible locations are:

1. **bootstrap**.properties/yaml → *spring.application.name=**boot.***
2. **application**.properties/yaml → *spring.application.name=**app.***
3. **environment** → *spring.application.name=**env.***
4. **environment** → *SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=**ENV_***

Code Example:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

// The same Object as applicationContext.getEnvironment()
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String appName;
...
// "Bootstrap" context: applicationContext.getParent()
String acp = applicationContext.getParent().getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.application.name");

// Application context: applicationContext
String ac = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.application.name");

String val = appName;
```

Possible definitions of *spring.application.name* in 1., 2. and/or 3., 4. and their values in *Spring Boot 3.2.2*:

| 1. | 2. | 3. | 4. | acp= | ac= | val= |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X** | - | - | - | **NPE** | **null** | **unresolvable** |
| - | **X** | - | - | **NPE** | **app.** | **app.** |
| **X** | **X** | - | - | **NPE** | **app.** | **app.** |
| X/- | X/- | **X** | - | **NPE** | env. | env. |
| X/- | X/- | - | **X** | **NPE** | ENV_ | ENV_ |
| X/- | X/- | **X** | **X** | **NPE** | ENV_ | ENV_ |

See: [The Bootstrap Application Context](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html)

> By default, **bootstrap properties** (**not bootstrap.properties** but properties that are loaded during the bootstrap phase) are added with high precedence, so **they cannot be overridden by local configuration**.

Hence *spring.application.name* is not a **bootstrap property**.