# What is the difference between putting a property on application.yml or bootstrap.yml in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

What is the difference between putting a property on application.yml or bootstrap.yml in spring boot?
In logging.config case, the application works differently.

Comment: `bootstrap.yml ` is as far as I can see specific to [`spring-cloud-config`]( http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_client)) and it's the configuration used to find the right configuration. So config there is probably loaded before application.properties/yaml

Answer (score 420, accepted):

I have just asked the `Spring Cloud` guys and thought I should share the info I have here.

**`bootstrap.yml` is loaded before `application.yml`.**

It is typically used for the following:

- when using Spring Cloud Config Server, you should specify `spring.application.name` and `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` inside `bootstrap.yml`
- some `encryption/decryption` information

Technically, `bootstrap.yml` is loaded by a parent Spring `ApplicationContext`. That parent `ApplicationContext` is loaded before the one that uses `application.yml`.

Comment: Could you please explain why Config Server need to put these parameters into `bootstrap.yml`?

Comment: When using Spring Cloud, the 'real' configuration data is usually loaded from a server. In order to get the URL (and other connection configuration, such as passwords, etc.), you need an earlier or "bootstrap" configuration. Thus, you put the config server attributes in the bootstrap.yml, which is used to load the real configuration data (which generally overrides what's in an application.yml [if present]).

Comment: some times i wonder when spring brings new exciting features it leaves behind convention over specification or they assume its already convention and nothing need not be specified and everything will be resolved on its own if not by spring then spring boot and may be in future spring-boot-boot ;)

Comment: When you say bootstrap.yml is loaded before application.yml. But when I remove application.yml. My application does not read bootstrap.yml. Why is that?

Comment: We need to highlight that the bootstrap file is never override because it has more precedence. According to the documentation [Team's Spring](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html)

Comment: @MikeMansell does it mean that when configuration is loading from Config Server, application.yml is ignored?

Comment: It will not get ignored. It's like bootstrap will be loaded first by parent Application Context and then application.yml by another Application Context.

Answer (score 122):

#### `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties`

It's only used/needed if you're using ***Spring Cloud*** and your application's configuration is stored on a remote configuration server (e.g. Spring Cloud Config Server).

From the documentation:

> A Spring Cloud application operates by creating a "bootstrap" context, which is a parent context for the main application. ***Out of the box it is responsible for loading configuration properties from the external sources***, and also decrypting properties in the local external configuration files.

Note that the `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` *can* contain additional configuration (e.g. defaults) but generally you only need to put bootstrap config here.

Typically it contains two properties:

- location of the configuration server (`spring.cloud.config.uri`)
- name of the application (`spring.application.name`)

Upon startup, Spring Cloud makes an HTTP call to the config server with the name of the application and retrieves back that application's configuration.

#### `application.yml` or `application.properties`

Contains standard application configuration - typically default configuration since any configuration retrieved during the bootstrap process will override configuration defined here.

Comment: That was very helpful! I was looking for a way yo store the environment-related VM options in a file, and ignore it from git repository! `bootstrap.properties` was a nice way to achieve it

Answer (score 57):

This answer has been very beautifully explained in book "**Microservices Interview Questions, For Java Developers (Spring Boot, Spring Cloud, Cloud
Native Applications)** by *Munish Chandel*, Version 1.30, 25.03.2018.

> The following content has been taken from this book, and total credit
>   for this answer goes to the Author of the book i.e. ***Munish
>   Chandel***

**application.yml**

*application.yml/application.properties* file is specific to Spring Boot applications. Unless you change the location of external properties of an application, spring boot will always load *application.yml* from the following location:

```
/src/main/resources/application.yml
```

You can store all the external properties for your application in this file. Common properties that are available in any Spring Boot project can be found at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html You can customize these properties as per your application needs. Sample file is shown below:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: foobar
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
server:
    port: 9000
```

**bootstrap.yml**

*bootstrap.yml* on the other hand is specific to *spring-cloud-config* and is loaded before the *application.yml*

*bootstrap.yml* is only needed if you are using Spring Cloud and your microservice configuration is stored on a remote Spring Cloud Config Server.

**Important points about bootstrap.yml**

1. When used with Spring Cloud Config server, you shall specify the application-name and config git location using below properties.

```
spring.application.name: "application-name"
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri: "git-uri-config"
```

2. When used with microservices (other than cloud config server), we need to specify the
   application name and location of config server using below properties

```
spring.application.name: 
spring.cloud.config.uri:
```

3. This properties file can contain other configuration relevant to Spring Cloud environment for e.g. eureka server location, encryption/decryption related properties.

*Upon startup, Spring Cloud makes an HTTP(S) call to the Spring Cloud Config Server with the name of the application and retrieves back that application’s configuration.*

*application.yml contains the default configuration for the microservice and any configuration retrieved (from cloud config server) during the bootstrap process will override configuration defined in application.yml*

Answer (score 11):

Well, I totally agree with answers already exist on this point:

- `bootstrap.yml` is used to save parameters that point out where the remote configuration is and **Bootstrap Application Context** is created with these remote configuration.

Actually, it is also able to store normal properties just the same as what `application.yml` do. But pay attention on this tricky thing:

- If you do place properties in `bootstrap.yml`, they will get lower precedence than almost any other property sources, including application.yml. As described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-commons.html#_application_context_hierarchies).

Let's make it clear, there are two kinds of properties related to `bootstrap.yml`:

- Properties that are loaded during the bootstrap phase. We use `bootstrap.yml` to find the properties holder (A file system, git repository or something else), and the properties we get in this way are with high precedence, so they cannot be overridden by local configuration. As described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-commons.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context).
- Properties that are in the `bootstrap.yml`. As explained early, they will get lower precedence. Use them to set defaults maybe a good idea.

So the differences between putting a property on `application.yml` or `bootstrap.yml` in spring boot are:

- Properties for loading configuration files in bootstrap phase can only be placed in `bootstrap.yml`.
- As for all other kinds of properties, place them in `application.yml` will get higher precedence.

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2 Cents here ..

Bootstrap.yml or Bootstrap.properties is used to fetch the config from Spring Cloud Server.

For Example, in My Bootstrap.properties file I have the following Config

```
spring.application.name=Calculation-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

On starting the application , It tries to fetch the configuration for the service by connecting to http://localhost:8888 and looks at Calculation-service.properties present in Spring Cloud Config server

You can validate the same from logs of Calcuation-Service when you start it up

`INFO 10988 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888`

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap.yml is used to fetch config from the server. It can be for a Spring cloud application or for others. Typically it looks like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: "app-name"
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${config.server:http://some-server-where-config-resides}
```

When we start the application it tries to connect to the given server and read the configuration based on spring profile mentioned in run/debug configuration.
[image: bootstrap.yml loads the first]

If the server is unreachable application might even be unable to proceed further. However, if configurations matching the profile are present locally the server configs get overridden.

**Good approach:**

Maintain a separate profile for local and run the app using different profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Another use for **bootstrap.yml** is to load configuration from kubernetes **configmap** and **secret** resources. The application must import the **spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes** dependency.

As with the Spring Cloud Config, this has to take place during the bootstrap phrase.

From the docs :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-k8s-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        name: default-name
        namespace: default-namespace
        sources:
         # Spring Cloud Kubernetes looks up a ConfigMap named c1 in namespace default-namespace
         - name: c1
```

So properties stored in the configmap resource with meta.name default-name can be referenced just the same as properties in **application.yml**

And the same process applies to secrets :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-k8s-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      secrets:
        name: default-name
        namespace: default-namespace
        sources:
         # Spring Cloud Kubernetes looks up a Secret named s1 in namespace default-namespace
         - name: s1
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap.yml is the first file loaded when you start spring boot application and application.property is loaded when application starts.
So, you keep, may be your config server's credentials etc., in bootstrap.yml which is required during loading application and then in application.properties you keep may be database URL etc.

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap.yml is used when you are using Spring Cloud and your application's configuration is stored on a remote configuration server (e.g. Spring Cloud Config Server). bootstrap.yml is loaded before application.yml