# How to pass JVM arguments in SpringBOOT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I would like to pass JVM arguments in the main spring boot class where we will be starting the spring boot application.

Could you please share how to set JVM arguments in spring boot application?

I tried the below options and there is no luck

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "X.X.X.X");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

or you can use this for spring boot

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties "property1": "value1", "property2": "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 35):

Add JVM arguments with -DargumentName i.e.

```
-DargumentName="value1"
```

Then in your spring application, you can retrieve the value by doing:

```
@Value("${argumentName}")
private String myVariable
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to add it in eclipse?

Answer (score 17):

Spring Boot has a pretty sophisticated environment variable and config properties management. You can do something as simple as this to pass foo with value "bar" via command line.

```
java -jar app.jar --foo="bar"
```

If you have not already, the link below has everything you need as far as ways of externalization of configuration in a Spring Boot application:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

**Update**:

If you are running a Spring Boot application, you should always run it using the pattern below:

```
$ java -jar <jar-name> [--key1="value1"]... [--keyN="valueN"]
```

And not using the command line suggested in some of the other comments here.

Answer (score 7):

JVM arguments you might add in `app.conf` file:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-Dyour_param=1234'
```

source: [SPRING DOCS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file)

Comment: Correct docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Answer (score 5):

You can set system properties with the -D switch when you start your application

```
java -DsomeProperty=123 your.package.name.YourMainClassName
```

Later in your code you can obtain a property value simply by calling

```
System.getPropetry("someProperty")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run your app like this:

```
$ java -server -Dmyproperty=blabla -jar myapp.jar
```

and you can access the value of myproperty in code.

Comment: what does `-D` mean ?

Comment: Remark: providing the options after `-jar myapp.jar` will not take them into account.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your app like this:

```
$ java -jar app.jar --someProperty=123
```

in application call:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
@Autowired
private Environment env;

String someProperty= env.getProperty("someProperty");
```

Comment: is this safe from a security point of view?

Answer (score 4):

When I run Spring Boot Apps with the Maven Plugin I have to set properties with `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguemtns=xxx` but this not really sets System-Properties but Spring-Properties (defined in application.xml)

here the command to start a spring boot app with properties:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Dserver.port=8399 -Dactivemq.url=http://localhost:61616"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the **@Value** annotation. For example

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.test}")
```

You can use it directly in a bean property, I have an example using in a parameter of a method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReviewsMicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(ReviewsMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean("value"));
    }

    @Bean
    public String value(@Value("#{systemProperties.test}")String value){
        return value;
    }
}
```

In order to execute the program you need to add the **test** property to the **JVM properties**.

```
 -Dtest="hallo reos"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    MyFantasticClass myFantasticClass;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(myFantasticClass.getMyFantasticProperty());
        };
    }
}

@Component
class MyFantasticClass{
    @Value("${myFantasticProperty}")
    String myFantasticProperty;
    
    String getMyFantasticProperty() {
        return myFantasticProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43269161/2073339) answer that explains `application.properties` and I started using `application.properties` to set up my environment-related variables

**bootstrap.properties:**

```
slack.channel=test
```

**bootstrap.yml:**

```yaml
slack: 
  channel: ${slack.channel}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your local environment to be always in UTF-8, then the easiest way is to define this inside your POM:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
```

You can also add multiple arguments inside it like this:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
```

Please note that this only works when you run the Spring Boot application in your local environment with following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

If you are using command line java to run your Spring Boot application, then you should either save the parameter as an environment variable or run Java with the argument like the other answers have mentioned.