# How to pass empty string as a command line property to Spring?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, properties, command-line-arguments

FYI: I am using Intellij's 'Run/Debug Configurations' tool.

I would like to pass an empty string as a property to my app via the command line:

```
--spring.ldap.username=
```

I have tried:

```
--spring.ldap.username= # results in parse error
--spring.ldap.username=''
--spring.ldap.username="" # results in parse error
--spring.ldap.username=\"\"
```

The attempts that actually parsed successfully yielded incorrect values, as demonstrated when I try to print the 'empty' Strings:

```
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("spring.ldap.username"));

// returns:
// ''
// ""
```

Setting the same property to an empty string in the application.properties file works perfectly:

```
spring.ldap.username=
```

The same print statement:

```
// returns:
//
// ^^ totally empty string
```

Is there a trick I am missing?

Comment: Can you enter them via `Environment variables` in the Run/Debug configuration for the application?

Comment: That might work, but I want to pass these arguments via the command line.

Comment: You may be overthinking this - wouldn't just defaulting the value of that parameter to an empty string in-code suffice? Is there a specific need to ingest the empty string as a parameter?

Comment: I think it would simplify code elsewhere in my system if passing an empty string (a sensible value in this case) to the flag doesn't break things. That being said, I will probably go with your suggestion for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it turns out, this can be accomplished by using regular JVM arguments.

Instead of

```
--my.property=
```

use

```
-Dmy.property=
```

Native JVM arguments are able to accept empty Strings I guess.

In IntelliJ, you can add them in the respective fields in the Run/Debug Configurations window as shown below:

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635316/2434726) to another question also has some more information on passing JVM arguments to Spring applications.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `--spring.ldap.username` (if you leave the `=`, it will parse as null)

Comment: I misread your answer; this works as well. I am not sure why I never thought to try this.