# Unable to execute HTTP request : Couldn't Kickstart Handshaking

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, jmeter, aws-sdk

I am trying to hit my Spring Boot Server(2.1.4) with 500 user threads using JMeter(5.0). while trying this I got the error in JMeter log file which is about 1% of the Samples. Spring Boot server is connecting to aws services .

> Unable to execute HTTP request : Couldn't Kickstart Handshaking

Both the JMeter and SpringBoot Server is Running on AWS EC2 instance (m5a.2xlarge)

Note: When I run Jmeter and Spring Boot Server in different instance Error got reduced to 0.1%

- JDK - openjdk version 11

[image: while logging in the spring boot server we got this Exception Details]

This shows aws sdkclient exception.Do we need to change anything awsclient configuration or its problem with our spring boot-server?

Comment: looks like your application is trying to make too many connections or reconnecting too fast to the AWS service. So you probably will have to redesign your applicaiton logic using the AWS service.

Comment: But we have increased the max connections to 1000 in the aws client configuration.So 500 threads can easily make connections to the aws service.

Comment: what AWS service are you accessing? Can it be that this service has some limit on the connections?

Comment: we are accessing QLDB service. I didn't see any document mentioning limits on connection.

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to [TLS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol versions mismatch, if you have the same application working fine on one AWS instance and doesn't working on another you can add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.debug=ssl
```

and compare the output for both instances, it should [enable SSL debugging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) hence give you a clue regarding what is the cause of the error.

Blind shot: try explicitly setting TLS protocol version for both JMeter and your Spring Boot application

1. JMeter: add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   https.default.protocol=TLS
   https.socket.protocols=TLSv1
   ```
2. Your application: add the next JVM arguments:

   ```
   -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3
   -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3
   ```

References:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [How to pass JVM arguments in SpringBOOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635176/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-in-springboot)

Comment: The original post says that only some connections fail, and the proportion of failures decreases when more resources can be dedicated. If this were a configuration problem, then either all connections would succeed or all would fail. This is likely due to some kind of throttling or connection limit.