# How to pass a parameter as an environment variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How do you pass a parameter as an environment variable?

Step 1: Open up user bash file 'vim ~/.bash_profile', write the environment variable and save the file

```
export TWLIO_NUMBER=+303....
```

Step 2: In the application porperties file, store the variable

```
twlio_number=${TWLIO_NUMBER}
```

Step 3: Import Value in order to use it

```
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

  @Value("${twlio_number}")
  private String TWILIO_NUMBER;
```

Also, if I hardcode the value in the application properties file, the code works.

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: Use `System.getenv("TWLIO_NUMBER")` to get the value of the exported environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Pass those as Java-Opts. It will work.

[How to pass JVM arguments in SpringBOOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635176/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-in-springboot)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0):

So I have a system variable in my spring project.

```java
String dataSourceUrl = System.getenv(DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
```

I am looking for something quick to set the variable in command line.

1. I found this command work in mac
   `export DEFAULT_CONNECTION=value` (value wrap in single quote to prevent the values being replaced)
2. You can check by env | grep DEFAULT_CONNECTION
3. run as usual `mvn spring-boot:run`