# Spring Cloud Config Client: Fetching config from wrong server

Tags: spring-cloud-config

When I run my Spring Cloud Config Client project config-client, I found these error:

```
2018-02-09 10:31:09.885  INFO 13933 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2018-02-09 10:31:10.022  WARN 13933 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/config-client/dev/master": 拒绝连接 (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接 (Connection refused)
2018-02-09 10:31:10.026  INFO 13933 --- [           main] c.y.c.ConfigClientApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-09 10:31:10.040  INFO 13933 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@33b1c5c5: startup date [Fri Feb 09 10:31:10 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1ffe63b9
2018-02-09 10:31:10.419  INFO 13933 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=65226c2b-524f-3b14-8e17-9fdbc9f72d85
2018-02-09 10:31:10.471  INFO 13933 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25380e89] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-09 10:31:10.688  INFO 13933 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 10001 (http)
2018-02-09 10:31:10.697  INFO 13933 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.698  INFO 13933 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-02-09 10:31:10.767  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-09 10:31:10.768  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 727 ms
2018-02-09 10:31:10.861  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.864  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.864  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.864  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.865  INFO 13933 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.895  WARN 13933 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClientApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'content' in value "${content}"
2018-02-09 10:31:10.896  INFO 13933 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-02-09 10:31:10.914  INFO 13933 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
```

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-09 10:31:10.923 ERROR 13933 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

Apparently, the config server is wrong. However, the Spring Cloud Config Server is running at localhost:10000/ and application.yml of the project(config-client) is below. Why the spring.cloud.config.uri doesn't work?

**application.yml [config-client]**

```
server:
  port: 10001
spring:
  application:
    name: config-client
  cloud:
    config:
      label: master
      profile: dev
      uri: http://localhost:10000
```

Comment: Put it into `bootstrap.yml`

Comment: Thank you very mush, I add bootstrap.yml according to your help and spring cloud documentation. It works

Answer (score 5):

Fur future readers, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997352/what-is-the-difference-between-putting-a-property-on-application-yml-or-bootstra), when using Spring Cloud Config Server, we should specify basic *bootstrap*  settings such as : `spring.application.name` and `spring.cloud.config.uri` inside **bootstrap.yml** (or "bootstrap.properties").

Upon startup, Spring Cloud makes an HTTP call to the config server with the name of the application and retrieves back that application's configuration.

That's said, since we're externalizing our settings using Spring Cloud Config Server, any *default* configurations defined in **application.yml** (or "application.properties") will be **overridden** during the bootstrap process upon startup.

Answer (score 2):

you can load configuration servers before starting the Application, using bootstrap.yml
just add configuration server and application name

```
spring:
  application:
    name: clientTest
  cloud:
    config:
      uri:  http://localhost:8889
      enabled: true      
      fail-fast: true
```

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ Users: add the following override parameter in the run/Debug Configuration:

Name: `spring.cloud.config.uri`

Value: `http://your-server-here/config-server`

Answer (score 1):

**if we are using bootstrap.properties. we have to include this dependency in pom for spring-2.4.0+**

agregado para evitar un error al usar spring mayor que 2.4.0

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId> 
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was testing spring consul, which usually runs in 8500, i saw a different port in the log.  Found that the different port is due to following deplendency of spring cloud. Hence i just have to remove it.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```