# In spring-cloud project, is it ok to replace application.yml with bootstrap.yml totally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In `spring-cloud` projects, for some reason, need to put some properties into `bootstrap.yml`, so that to make the specific properties available earlier.

Then there are 2 config files: `bootstrap.yml` and `application.yml`.

Wondering is it ok to put everying into `bootstrap.yml`, and remove `application.yml` totally, to make it cleaner.

Since `bootstramp.yml` is just loaded earlier, it seems to be ok, right? Or, will this cause some issue in some case?

Comment: is application starting when you delete application.yml ? I dont think so it will.

Comment: @KarthickM It can start, there is no problem.

Comment: If its starting, than you should be ok. we source configs-props  form external config-src "https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration"  with no issues. As log as the config properties are  loaded and you can see them in localhost/actuator/env you will be ok. Bootstrap should be fine as the source of config props.

Comment: Can you edit your question so I can upvote.. it's saying I down-voted, probably by mistake :(

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar Partly, I did the same test before, it works fine so far, but still that can't prove it's ok for any case I guess.

Comment: properties in application.yml gets overridden provided by server, so when using Spring Cloud I can't find any specific reason to have configurations in applicatio.yml. Plus updated answer with reference.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar Properties from `config server` is similar as `application.yml`, and it's a good practice I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically idea is to get configurations from **ConfigServer** using Spring Cloud Config. But sometimes we need some configurations e.g. **spring.application.name** upfront so, I'm using those configurations in `bootstrap.yml`. Which generally overrides what's in an application.yml [if present]). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52643791/6332074)

Plus, yes you can put all your configurations in `bootstrap.yml` and it works simply fine. I've tested with more than four microservices.