# Spring Boot yml file read order

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have below files under resources folder in a standard Spring Boot app .
Spring.active.profile is set to dev
In which order the properties files are read .?

```
1)application.yml 
2)bootstrap.yml
3)application_dev.yml
4)bootstrap_dev.yml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) mentions

> Profile specific properties are loaded from the same locations as
> standard application.properties, with profiles specific files
> overriding the default ones

This would mean that first the `application.yml` is read and then the `application_dev.yml` is read and overrides values from the default `application.yml` if needed.

Same for `bootstrap.yml` and `bootstrap-dev.yml`

Also as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545152/7237884)

> bootstrap.yml is loaded before application.yml.

So to answer your question the order should be

1. bootstrap.yml
2. bootstrap_dev.yml
3. application.yml
4. application_dev.yml

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap files are always the first: bootstrap.yml then bootstrap-{profile}.yml. then application.yml and application-{profile}.yml.

the property values are overridden by the next files so:
`a: 1` from application.yml will be overridden by `a: 55` from application-{profile}.yml

Comment: Thanks.And if provide a property file outside jar then it will be first right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that external properties and env vars override the values from the .yml files.